# Recovering files from empty Linux partition

Tags: linux-mint, partition, data-recovery, gparted, testdisk

On my Linux setup, I had a separate partition for my /home directory. I had Linux Mint XFCE 19.2 and updated to 19.3 Cinnamon.

However after the update my user was gone and after making a new one, the old home partition was empty. The new home is on a partition different from the old one, but the old one was seemingly wiped.

I ran Photorec, Foremost and RLinux on the partition. Photorec and Foremost got the files out in random order and no proper file names. RLinux managed to restore all of the folders, but none of the files there are usable.

I began to reorder the files in the restored folders, but its 25GB of data and it's tedeous and I don't remember where everything is supposed to go.

I never used the partition since then, no changes have been made to it. I checked it with Thunar properties, as well as df -h and it registers use of 25GB of data on it, even though df -h says that of 465GB there are 434GB free wirh a usage of 1%.

GParted reads only 8GB used space and it couldn't repair the drive.

TestDisk recognises the immediate files and folders on the partitions "root", but upon trying to access the folder, it returns a message "No files found, file system may be damaged"

Timeshift is also not an option, since after the new uset was created, it had no snapshots of the partition and it has now been a month.

Every method I've tried so far has managed to give me part of what I need and I'm getting indications that the entire filesystem is there, but no tool I've tried so far has been able to fully repair the files.

Am I missing something? Is there any other method I could use?